# Why does Throwable.printStackTrace takes a PrintWriter, instead of a Writer?

Tags: java, printstacktrace

Why does [`public void printStackTrace(PrintStream s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29) in the *Throwable* class take a PrintWriter, instead of a Writer?

I think Writer should be the norm (*code to the interface, not a specific implementation*), but it could be something that I'm missing, hence this question.

Comment: A Writer is not an interface, it is an abstract class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html

Comment: Appendable is an interface implemented by Writer.

Comment: @joergl: You're right. I meant "interface" in in the design sense, which covers (some) abstract classes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Writer` is an abstract class which `PrintWriter` extends. `Throwable.printStackTrace` takes a `PrintWriter` because it calls the `println` method on it which is not available in the `Writer` class.`println` is called because it needs to print the stack trace, one stack frame per line.

Comment: Thanks @Abhinav: this makes sense. That being said, rather than having a wrapper class, it would have been great to have all sugar functionality (like println) directly into Writer. This would have minimized the hierarchy, streamlined the usage, and saved one extra object too :-).

Answer (score 1):

There could be a couple of reason

- The original implementation was to use PrintStream and the improved version of that is PrintWriter.
- The method prints lines of text and while it could create a PrintWriter on demand this is not ideal.

What they could have done is accept a Appendable which is the parent of Writer like this.

```
public void printStackTrace(Appendable appendable) {
    PrintWriter pw = (appendable instanceof PrintWriter) ? (PrintWriter) appendable :
        (appendable instanceof Writer) ? new PrintWriter((Writer) appendable) :
        new printWriter(new AppendableWriter(appendable));
```